# Probit estimation in r

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to estimate a probit model that looks at the predictive power of certain leading indicators in predicting downturns in the economy. I have converted the variables to ts and everything looks ok.

The problem is that when I try to run regressions at different lags, the coefficients are all the same. I have been using the lag(var.ts,k=1) to lag the independent variables.

I see a lot of responses suggest using dynlm. But I don't know if this is appropriate given the dichotomous nature of the dependent variable.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dyn` package for that

```
require(dyn)

set.seed(1)
y <- ts(sample(c(0, 1), size = 15, replace = TRUE), start = c(2000, 2), freq = 4)
x <- ts(1:15, start = c(2000, 2), freq = 4)

dyn$glm(y ~ lag(x, k = 1), family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

One more comment on the use of `lag`, `lag(x, 1)` correspond to x_{t+1} and `lag(x, -1)` to x_{t-1}